$X$ is measurable w.r.t $\sigma(X_1,X_2)$, then $X=f(X_1,X_2)$ for some measurable $f$?
It is relatively easy to show that $X$ must be a function of $X_1,X_2$. One just need to verify that $X$ must be constant on any level set $\{\omega|(X_1(\omega),X_2(\omega))=(a,b)\}$.
It would be nice if something can be said about the function. Measurability looks like the weakest requirement.
However, it seems that nothing prevents the preimage $f^{-1}(B)$ of a Borel set $B$ is non-measurable in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but $(X_1,X_2)^{-1}\circ f^{-1}(B)$ is measurable. Afterall, nothing is said about the measurability of the preimage of a non-measurable set.
So could we conclude that $f$ must be measurable? And how?

A slight simplification: since $\mathbb{R}^2$ is Borel-isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, there’s no reason to have both $X_1$ and $X_2$. It is just equivalent to the question as to whether $X$ being $\sigma(Y)$-measurable implies $X = f(Y)$ for some Borel $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

@DavidGao. I am not familiar with the concept of Borel isomorphism. Just googled it. So if $\phi:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ is a Borel isomorphism, then $Y\equiv\phi(X_1,X_2)$ is a real-valued r.v. with $\sigma(Y)=\sigma(X_1,X_2)$. Then $X=f(Y)$ implies that $X=f\circ \phi(X_1,X_2)$. Thanks for point it out.

Let $X:(\Omega,\mathscr{F})\to(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})),Y:(\Omega,\mathscr{F})\to (\Omega',\mathscr{F}')$ be measurable functions and suppose $\sigma(X)\subseteq \sigma(Y)\subseteq \mathscr{F}$. The standard argument of the factorisation lemma uses the so-called standard machine: (a) prove that if $X$ is a simple function then there exists a measurable $f:(\Omega',\mathscr{F}')\to (\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ s.t. $X=f(Y)$; (b) repeat for nonnegative $X$ and conclude for general $X$.
(a) If $X=\sum_{k\leq n}a_k\mathbf{1}_{A_k}$ where $(A_k)_{k\leq n}$ are disjoint. Then, for each $k$, $A_k=\{X=a_k\}=\{Y \in B_k\}$, for some $B_k\in \mathscr{F}'$ (because $\sigma(X)\subseteq \sigma(Y)$) and so $X(\omega)=\sum_{k\leq n}a_k\mathbf{1}_{A_k}(\omega)=\sum_{k\leq n}a_k\mathbf{1}_{B_k}(Y(\omega))$. We have found that $f(y)=\sum_{k\leq n}a_k\mathbf{1}_{B_k}(y)$, which is measurable because each $\mathbf{1}_{B_k}:\Omega'\to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable due to $(B_k)_{k\leq n}$ being $\mathscr{F}'$-measurable sets. Indeed, recall that $\sigma(\mathbf{1}_{B_k})=\{\emptyset,B_k,B_k^c,\Omega'\}\subset \mathscr{F}'$.
(b) If $X$ is nonnegative, we have a nondecreasing sequence $(X^n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of simple functions that increase to $X$. The standard construction is $X^n=\sum_{0\leq k<n2^n}k2^{-n}\mathbf{1}_{\{X \in [k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n})\}}+n\mathbf{1}_{\{X\geq n\}}$ and by (a) we find a corresponding sequence of measurable functions $f^n(y)=\sum_{0\leq k<n2^n}k2^{-n}\mathbf{1}_{B_{k,n}}(y)+n\mathbf{1}_{B_{n2^n,n}}(y)$ such that $X^n=f^n(Y)$. Now we know that pointwise $\lim_nf^n(Y)=\lim_nX^n=X$. So if we define $f:=\liminf_nf^n$ (this trick is due to R. Schilling) we get that $f$ is measurable and $f(Y)=\liminf_nf^n(Y)=\lim_nf^n(Y)=X$. If $X$ is not necessarily nonnegative, we find $f^{+},f^{-}$ similarly as above such that $X^+=f^{+}(Y),X^-=f^{-}(Y)$ so $f:=f^+-f^-$, which is measurable, satisfies our requirement.

Thanks. I didn't think about starting from the simple function case.
